# React Hook Form change default values after API call

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

How do I update the default values once the API has been called?

This is what I want to achieve:

- I have a card where I can see a comment.
- There is a button that toggles a textField that allows me to add/edit/delete a comment
- I can also discard changes I was making before saving an edition, to do so I will show the original defaultValues

Now let's say I've already left a comment `Comment test 1`, so when the card is rendered it will show the comment by using the injected data of the `defaultValues`. I edit the comment to `Comment test 2`, and click save, now the comment shown comes from the state value, not from the default values. Now I want to edit to `Comment Test 3`, but I change my mind and discard the changes. Now the card will show default values `Comment Test 1`, while it should show `Comment Test 2`.

So I guess there's a way to update the defaultValues once the API has been called, I have tried on success to use
`resetField('comment', { defaultValue: { ...comment } });`, but the default comment is not updated.

What would be a better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, storing the values you save in a variable (e.g. `overwrittenForm`) Than use the `formContext.reset(overwrittenForm)` from the useForm hook and pass it the variable to reset to the latest state.